# Plot of Solution?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I am trying to plot the following code, but it is not giving me anything?

```
Plot[Solve[(5.520991425261603`*^-8+(-0.001398476931794204`+0.0006878719483383239` qos) L^2+(-0.0010488601488791106`+0.0009896449725060321` qos) L^4+(-0.00010808845678108988`+(4.0000538090831945` -4.` qos) qos)L^6+(0.00001668022738665996` +(-1.0000376525407901`+qos) qos) L^8)==0,L],{qos,1,1.2}]
```

I tried with NSolve as well but still nothing.

Comment: Start by fixing a value for `qos`, say `qos=1.01`, then run the `Solve[...]` command and see if this is something you can plot as is.

Comment: @Bill Still nothing.

Comment: Most solutions are non-real complexes, what precisely do you want to plot?

Comment: @A.G.  At 1.2 the value of L should be around 2 and at 1 the value should be 0... so, I'll get the exponential increasing graph.

Comment: If you try `L /. NSolve[((5.520991425261603*^-8
       + (-0.001398476931794204 + 0.0006878719483383239 qos) L^2
       + (-0.0010488601488791106 + 0.0009896449725060321 qos) L^4
       + (-0.00010808845678108988 + (4.0000538090831945 - 
             4. qos) qos) L^6
       + (0.00001668022738665996 + (-1.0000376525407901 + 
             qos) qos) L^8)
     /. qos -> 1) == 0, L]` the solution is `{-1.34468 - 1.0499 I, -1.34468 + 1.0499 I, -0.00881441, 0. - 2. I, 
 0. + 2. I, 0.00881441, 1.34468 - 1.0499 I, 1.34468 + 1.0499 I}`.

Comment: You can try finding only real solutions and take maximal (or last) of them: `sol[qos_]:=L/.Solve[...here your equation goes ...==0,L,Reals]`, then `Plot[Max[sol[qos]],{qos,1,1.2}]`, it has sharp peak near `qos=1`.